# Add element up to the up to the divisible element by five

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a prooblem. I always have five elements.
If an element with the `label == 'speed'` exists, it should be padded up to five elements. So that
If a `label == 'normal'` exists, in the fifth + 1 position is.

What is wrong with my logic?

```dart
widgetList = [
{label = 'speed'},
{label = 'normal'},
{label = 'normal'},
{label = 'normal'},
{label = 'normal'},
]

      for(var i = 0; i <widgetList.length; i++ ) {
        if(widgetList[i].label?.modus == 'normal') {
          isParking = true;
        }
      }

      if(isParking) {
        int j = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i <widgetList.length; i++ ) {
          //print(widgetList.length);
          //print(i);
          if(widgetList[i].label?.modus == 'normal') {
            print("i: $i");
            if(i % 5 == 0) {
              print("i $i is divisble by 5");
              break;
            }
            else {
                print("i $i is NOT divisble by 5");
                widgetList.insert(i + j, LabelButton.createBlank());
                print("j is $j");
                j++;

            }
            /*widgetList.insert(i, LabelButton.createBlank());
            widgetList.insert(i + 1, LabelButton.createBlank());
            widgetList.insert(i + 2, LabelButton.createBlank());
            widgetList.insert(i + 3, LabelButton.createBlank());*/
            break;
          }
        }
      }
```

The following is not what I want. I does not work for me well. It is more like this:

```dart
widgetList = [
{label = 'speed'},
LabelButton.createBlank(),
LabelButton.createBlank(),
{label = 'normal'},
{label = 'normal'},
LabelButton.createBlank(),
{label = 'normal'},
{label = 'normal'},
]
```

What I want

```dart
widgetList = [
{label = 'speed'},
LabelButton.createBlank(),
LabelButton.createBlank(),
LabelButton.createBlank(),
LabelButton.createBlank(),
{label = 'normal'},
{label = 'normal'},
{label = 'normal'},
{label = 'normal'},
]
```

Another Example

```dart
widgetList = [
{label = 'speed'},
{label = 'speed'},
{label = 'speed'},
{label = 'speed'},
{label = 'normal'},
]
// What I want
widgetList = [
{label = 'speed'},
{label = 'speed'},
{label = 'speed'},
{label = 'speed'},
LabelButton.createBlank(),
{label = 'normal'},
]
```